# composer set a local repository (satis)

Tags: repository, composer-php, satis

I want to set a local Repository, so i set up satis.
I loaded SonataAdminBundle and KnpMenuBundle as an exemple.
satis.json:
`{"type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle"},{"type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle"}`

After that, in my project composer :

```
{"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://my.local.repo/"
    },
    { "packagist" : false }
],
"minimum-stability":"dev",
"require": {
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

}

when i do a composer update, i got this error:

```
  Problem 1
- sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master requires knplabs/knp-menu >=1.1.0,<3.0.0 -> no matching package found.
- sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master requires knplabs/knp-menu >=1.1.0,<3.0.0 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[dev-master].
```

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

what shall i do ?

Comment: i tryed with  {"knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master"} and composer works fine. Does the problem come from SonataAdminBundle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:
There is two bundles : knplabs/knp-menu-bundle and knplabs/knp-menu , I was downloading the wrong one.